# How do I insert values of elements that are part of the EmbeddedId in JPA?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, java-ee-8

I have a case where I need to execute an insert statement via createNativeQuery.  I have an entity list I'm looping through in order to set the properties accordingly from another bean class, and then persist that data to the oracle database.

The problem I am facing is persisting the data that is part of the embeddedId (item, loc, weekstart, type, forecastId, insertTS).  I need to persist that data for the new records to be inserted into the database.  When I try to set the values from the POJO bean to my set method for the properties of my entity bean, nothing happens.  Below is my code for setting the values of the properties from the POJO bean to my entity bean, along with my persistence method and the insert query being executed:

Validation class where validation occurs beforehand (missing to get the point) that includes the setting of my entity properties from the POJO bean:

```
List <InsertPromoData> insertPromos = new ArrayList<InsertPromoData>();
    promo.forEach(record -> {
        
        if (record.getErrorList().size() == 0) {
            rowsSuccessful++;
            Util.writeSuccessToFile(templateCd, successFile, record, successFields);
            try {
                InsertPromoData insertData = new InsertPromoData();
                insertData.getId().setItem(record.getItem());
                insertData.getId().setLoc(record.getLoc());
                insertData.getId().setWeekStart(record.getWeek_Start_Date());
                insertData.setNumberOfWeeks(record.getNumber_Of_Weeks());
                insertData.getId().setType(record.getType());
                insertData.getId().setForecastId(record.getForecast_ID());
                insertData.setQty(record.getUnits());
                insertPromos.add(insertData);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error with setting insertPromolist from promo list values and the error is " + e.getMessage());
            }
            
        } 
        else {
            if (rowsFailure == 0) {
                Util.writeHeaderToFile(templateCd, errorFile);
            }
            rowsFailure++;
            Util.writeErrorToFile(templateCd, errorFile, record, record.getErrorList());
        }
    });
    
    errorFile.close();
    successFile.close();
    
    OracleImpl.insertPromoData(insertPromos);
```

POJO bean (promo is the variable representing this list of beans in validation class above):

```
public class PromoBean extends ErrorListBean
{
    public String Item;
    public String Loc;
    public String Week_Start_Date;
    public String Units;
    public String Forecast_ID;
    public String Type;
    public String Number_Of_Weeks;
        
    public String getItem() {
        return Item;
    }
    public void setItem(String item) {
        Item = item;
    }
    public String getLoc() {
        return Loc;
    }
    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        Loc = loc;
    }
    public String getWeek_Start_Date() {
        return Week_Start_Date;
    }
    public void setWeek_Start_Date(String week_Start_Date) {
        Week_Start_Date = week_Start_Date;
    }
    public String getNumber_Of_Weeks() {
        return Number_Of_Weeks;
    }
    public void setNumber_Of_Weeks(String number_Of_Weeks) {
        Number_Of_Weeks = number_Of_Weeks;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        Type = type;
    }
    public String getForecast_ID() {
        return Forecast_ID;
    }
    public void setForecast_ID(String forecast_ID) {
        Forecast_ID = forecast_ID;
    }
    public String getUnits() {
        return Units;
    }
    public void setUnits(String units) {
        Units = units;
    }
}
```

Embeddable class representing the composite primary key of the table:

```
@Embeddable
public class PromoID implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name = "ITEM")
    private String item;
 
    @Column(name = "LOC")
    private String loc;
    
    @Column(name = "WK_START")
    private String weekStart;
    
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;
    
    @Column(name = "FCSTID")
    private String forecastId;
    
    @Column(name = "U_TIMESTAMP")
    private String insertTS;
    
    public PromoID() {
        
    }
    
    public PromoID (String item, String loc, String weekStart, String type, String forecastId, String insertTS) {
        this.item = item;
        this.loc = loc;
        this.weekStart = weekStart;
        this.type = type;
        this.forecastId = forecastId;
        this.insertTS = insertTS;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public String getWeekStart() {
        return weekStart;
    }

    public void setWeekStart(String weekStart) {
        this.weekStart = weekStart;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getForecastId() {
        return forecastId;
    }

    public void setForecastId(String forecastId) {
        this.forecastId = forecastId;
    }

    public String getInsertTS() {
        return insertTS;
    }

    public void setInsertTS(String insertTS) {
        this.insertTS = insertTS;
    }
    //hashcode and equals methods
```

Persistence Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "U_USER_PROMO")
public class InsertPromoData {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PromoID id;
    @Column(name="NUMBER_OF_WEEKS")
    String numberOfWeeks;
    
    @Column(name="QTY")
    String qty;
    
    @Id
    @AttributeOverrides(
            {
                @AttributeOverride(name = "item",column = @Column(name="ITEM")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "loc", column = @Column(name="LOC")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "weekStart", column = @Column(name="WK_START")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name="TYPE")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "forecastId", column = @Column(name="FCSTID"))
            }
    )

    public PromoID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(PromoID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNumberOfWeeks() {
        return numberOfWeeks;
    }

    public void setNumberOfWeeks(String numberOfWeeks) {
        this.numberOfWeeks = numberOfWeeks;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}
```

DAO class method to execute the update (entitymanagerfactory emf already initialized):

```
public static void insertPromoData(List<InsertPromoData> insertData) {

          logger.debug("Execution of method insertPromoData in Dao started");
          System.out.println("Size of the insertData list is " + insertData.size());
          EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

          try {
              em.getTransaction().begin();    
              System.out.println("Beginning transaction for insertPromoData");
              Query query = em.createNativeQuery(env.getProperty("insertPromoUploadData"));
              for (InsertPromoData promoData : insertData) {
                  query.setParameter("item", promoData.getId().getItem());
                  query.setParameter("location", promoData.getId().getLoc());
                  query.setParameter("wkStart", promoData.getId().getWeekStart());
                  query.setParameter("numberOfWeeks", promoData.getNumberOfWeeks());        
                  query.setParameter("type", promoData.getId().getType());
                  query.setParameter("fcstId", promoData.getId().getForecastId());
                  query.setParameter("quantity", promoData.getQty());
                  query.executeUpdate();
              }
              em.getTransaction().commit();
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
              logger.error("Exception in beginning transaction");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
              em.clear();
              em.close();
          }
            
          logger.debug("Execution of method insertPromoData in Dao ended");
    }
```

Query in properties file:

```
insertPromoUploadData = INSERT INTO {h-schema}U_USER_PROMO (ITEM, LOC, WK_START, NUMBER_OF_WEEKS, TYPE, FCSTID, QTY, U_TIMESTAMP) VALUES (:item, :location, TO_DATE(:wkStart,'MM DD YYYY'), :numberOfWeeks, :type, :fcstId, :quantity, SYSDATE)
```

My list size from my DAO class is returning as 0 once I begin the transaction and not sure why it is empty.  Is there a reason that it is empty?  I'm trying to persist each of the fields to the database (including the composite key fields) via insert query.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this for hours, I finally came to the conclusion that the simplest way to executeUpdate() without running into issues due to my current @EmbeddedId/@Embeddable logic was to change it to use **@IdClass** for my composite PK class, and annotate the fields from the PK in my entity with @Id.  This allowed my data to be persisted to the database.  Another slight difference was adding the **insertTS** in my entity class and annotating with @Id and generating getters/setters.  This was necessary for JPA to recognize all the properties being referenced that I am wanting to persist, though I am persisting insertTS using SYSDATE function from the oracle DB instead of utilizing the get/set methods and setting to the current time from the java side.

I am sure there is a way to use @EmbeddedId/@Embeddable logic and be able to persist the fields that are part of the EmbeddedId, however, this I found to be a more simplistic way of doing it without further complexity in the code.